# When I stop and start embedded Mule runtime, sometimes I get this error saying an instance of Mule is already running

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

When I stop and start embedded Mule runtime, sometimes I get this error saying an instance of Mule is already running, do you want to restart, but in reality there is no instance running.

I was expecting for the Mule runtime to start without any issues since I had already stopped it.

Comment: When applying tags, check the tag notes to check they are relevant.  This is not an [embedded] (embedded systems) question and [integration] and [runtime] are too generic to be useful, and the [mulesoft] tag notes explicitly advise that [mule-esb] should be used for this question instead.

Comment: mule-esb is an obsolete tag since current versions should use mule or mule4. This is about the Mule runtime inside Anypoint Studio.

Comment: The question doesn't provide any useful details to understand the issue. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution to this, hope this is helpful to someone who is facing the same issue.

1. In your C:\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.4.0.ee_7.11.0.202208251955\mule\bin folder, delete the files ending with .pid
2. In this folder C:\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.4.0.ee_7.11.0.202208251955\mule.mule you will see folders for your projects, make sure you delete them.

Start the runtime and you will not see this error. This helped and solved my problem.